# read all text file and put in arguments

Tags: bash, unix

How do we read all text files and put in arguments so we can process it for variable?

```
1.txt -->100
2.txt -->200
..
9.txt -->900

$ ./read.sh 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt 4.txt 5.txt 6.txt 7.txt 8.txt 9.txt
```

read.sh:

```
$file1=$1
$file2=$2
...
$file9=$9
```

But it inserts "1.txt" instead 100, how we can get the value of file instead the name of file?

Comment: it seems to me you're not going about this the right way, unless the number of files is fixed always. Even then, a loop (with arrays?) would be a far better match than 'numbered' variables

Comment: @sehe: yes you are right. I read too fast the question. A loop inside read script with the path to files as parameters is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly. If you want to put the content of the files you pass as arguments to the script into the variables `$file1`, `$file2`, etc. you should make `read.sh` look like this:

```
file1=$(<"$1")
file2=$(<"$2")
...
file9=$(<"$9")
```

Note that when assigning a value to a variable you must use the variable name without a leading `$`.

A more general solution (provided you're using bash 4) might look like this:

```
declare -A files

while [ -n "$1" ]; do
  files[$1]=$(<"$1")
  shift
done
```

`declare -A` creates an associative array (or dictionary) where you can store name→value mappings, e.g. filename→content.

Comment: Now, replace `$(cat "$1")` by `$(< "$1")` to avoid launching a separate process each time :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [xargs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs). Try this command in the directory where are your .txt files:

```
cat * | xargs ./read.sh
```

Alternatively:

```
./read.sh `cat *`
```